# What is the best way to do extensive null checks in F# when calling C# code

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I would like to know the best way to interact with C# code from F# in a functional way, when I have to check null many times.

From C#, is easy because I have null operator

```
public bool Authorize(DashboardContext dashboardContext)
{
    var context = new OwinContext(dashboardContext.GetOwinEnvironment());
    var user = context.Authentication.User;
    return user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
}
```

From F#, I made this

```
let authorize (ctx:DashboardContext) =
    match OwinContext(ctx.GetOwinEnvironment()) with
    | null -> false
    | c -> match c.Authentication.User with
            | null -> false
            | user -> user.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

But I am not happy with this. What is the functional way for doing this right? I thought maybe some computation expression would help, but I don't know how to accomplish yet.

Comment: Your solution looks fine for this use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Option.ofObj` will convert a nullable object into an `Option`. Then you can use the helpers already defined in the `Option` module. For example, part of the pattern that you've written there is already encapsulated by `Option.bind`.

```
let authorize (ctx:DashboardContext) =
    ctx.GetOwinEnvironment() |> OwinContext |> Option.ofObj
    |> Option.bind (fun c -> c.Authentication.User |> Option.ofObj)
    |> Option.map  (fun user -> user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    |> Option.defaultValue false
```

`Option.bind` takes an `Option<'a>` and a function that takes the type `'a` and returns an `Option<'a>`. When it is used in a pipeline it's a way of "mapping" a `Some` or filtering it out into a `None`.

I would say that the function you wrote looks fine actually, but this way might be considered a little bit more idiomatic, though it's arguably also a bit harder to follow in this example. `Option.bind` really comes into its own when it saves multiple levels of nesting.

It's worth noting that in both your F# function and mine we're assuming non-nullness of the `Authentication` and `Identity` properties and risking null reference exceptions when accessing their properties. That's in contrast to the C# method using null propagation. There isn't currently a built-in way to do that in F# but there are probably some advanced methods for simulating it.

It is also possible to do this with computation expressions. See the `MaybeBuilder` [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/).

Comment: You deserve your username, Mr. **Quick** Brown Fox: I had only just started writing my answer, and yours is far more complete. :-) I'll mention, though, that in some cases the simple `isNull` function (which just returns `true` if its input is null, and `false` if its input is not null) can be useful as well. Sometimes that's all you need. But in cases like this where you have a chain of steps, the `Option` type is almost always better (especially if the nulls could show up at many points in the chain).

Comment: Another consideration: the result of the constructor call (`OwinContext`) does not need to be null-checked. A constructor call can never result in a null.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin a drawback of using a constructor like a regular function.  Hard to reason about things of this sort.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks folks!

Answer (score 1):

I liked *TheQuickBrownFox*'s idea of using `Option.ofObj`, but I still found it tedious to write with the built-in functions, so I wrote a custom operator to chain null checks:

```ml
let inline (>>?) f g = f >> Option.bind (g >> Option.ofObj)
```

With this operator, what in C# would be

```cs
user?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false
```

Becomes:

```ml
user
|> (Option.ofObj
    >>? (fun x -> x.Identity)
    >>? (fun x -> x.IsAuthenticated)
    >> Option.defaultValue false)
```

Which is much prettier!

Disclaimer: I've been using F# for maybe two or three weeks total, so this might be completely stupid :)